# Load and After in same method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somebody know if there´s component on JQuery that make the load and append at the same time?.

I would like to do is instead this:

```
    $.get("url", function (data) {
            $("#table_items tbody tr:last").after(data);
    });
```

Somethig like

```
    $("#table_items tbody tr:last").loadAndAfter(url);
```

Looking here and on Google I could not find an implementation as load+after

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... do you just mean the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method from jQuery, which loads the content from a given URL into the selected element?

`$("#table_items tbody tr:last").load(url);`

Edit: ah, missed the after...

You could do something like:

`$("#table_items tbody tr:last").after('<tr></tr>').load(url + " tr");`

This will depend on what is returned in from the URL though.

Comment: there´s still two steps, I was looking for just one step, if exits. Thanks anyway

Comment: You could write a function that does it if you wanted it to be just one step. I'm not sure on the benefit of that though as it's only a few characters you'd be saving. Unless you need to run lots of times.

Comment: Of course I can create my own method, actually I have, but still, is a very usefull feature, and I was wondering if in JQuery already exist something like that.